# Using an NSButton with SpriteKit

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

I'm a tyro Cocoa programmer trying to learn something about Swift/Cocoa/SpriteKit by modifying the default OS X code. So this is probably a basic question but I haven't been able to find a solution.

I wanted to add functionality to delete all the Spaceship sprites you get after clicking with the mouse so I added these methods to class: GameScene.

```
override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent!) {
    if (theEvent.characters) == "p" {
        removeSprites()
    }
}

func removeSprites() {
    self.removeAllChildren()
    println(self)  // Here to track down my problem.
}
```

So it works when I press 'p' and `println(self)` tells me `self` is 
    `<SKScene> name:'(null)' frame:{{0, 0}, {1024, 768}}`

---

So next I set-up an NSButton in SKView in Interface Builder and connected it to an IBAction in `class: AppDelegate`

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
   GameScene().removeSprites()
    }
```

However this time the sprites aren't removed and the println reports

```
<SKScene> name:'(null)' frame:{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}
```

So I'm confused about this 'other' SKScene.

How to I code the NSButton to effect a sprite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GameScene() is a new instance of your class, not the one that "self" is referring to in your earlier method.

Your IBAction is in the AppDelegate, not in the GameScene, so you need to keep a reference to the scene - if you're using the default template, there should be a reference to it in applicationDidFinishLaunching... Hang on to that as a property, then you can say self.scene!.removeSprites() in your action.

```
var scene: GameScene? = nil

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        self.scene = scene 
        // ...
    }
}
@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.scene!.removeSprites()
}
```