# How do I use AppKit elements in a OS X SpriteKit game?

Tags: macos, sprite-kit, appkit, nsbutton

I'm trying to use AppKit elements like NSButtons and NSPopUpButtons in my OS X SpriteKit game. For iOS, I know you can use UIKit, but you can't use UIKit with an OS X SpriteKit game. I tried to add the button on top of the SKView, but it's not showing up. I took a look at the following post ([Using an NSButton with SpriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426179/using-an-nsbutton-with-spritekit)), but it's not clear to me as to how I should proceed. How do I make all the proper connections (for the button or any other AppKit UI element) via code and/or the xib file so that it shows up in my scene?

[EDIT] I went through the Apple SpriteKit game example ("Adventure") and it appears that they have added an NSButton to their SKView somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from a tutorial video, but I can't find the video anymore sadly. However, a way to do it is to display a sheet on top of the game and keep your cocoa controls in a xib file separate from the spritekit stuff.

I've included the code below for showing a sheet in a spritekit setting.

It needs a window .xib file as well (so make sure you pick the window one). Wire up the .sheetWindow property to the window, and the files owner to the classes included below. Also I've wired up a button in the xib file to the "closeWindow:" method, but that's entirely optional.

This example is for editing NSManagedObjects, but I've removed a bulk of the actual editing code in between to make the example clearer. I've retained the delegate, because you often want to call back to the spritekit which opens it.

You show the sheet by creating a object of the below classes and calling "showWindowFor..." method. This method takes an NSManagedObject, but this is of course totally optional. You can make a method just called "-(void)showWindow".

.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol AttributeEditorSheetDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) attributeEditorSavedObject;

@end

@interface AttributeEditorSheet : NSObject {
    NSManagedObject * _editedObject;
}

@property (weak,nonatomic) id <AttributeEditorSheetDelegate> delegate;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow * sheetWindow;
- (IBAction)closeWindow:(NSButton *)sender;

-(void) showWindowForNSManagedObject:(NSManagedObject *)editedObject;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "AttributeEditorSheet.h"

@implementation AttributeEditorSheet

-(void) showWindowForNSManagedObject:(NSManagedObject *)editedObject {
    if (self.sheetWindow==nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AttributeEditorWindow" owner:self topLevelObjects:nil];
    }

    _editedObject = editedObject;


    [[NSApplication sharedApplication].mainWindow beginSheet:self.sheetWindow completionHandler:nil];
}


- (IBAction)closeWindow:(NSButton *)sender {
    [self.delegate attributeEditorSavedObject];
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication].mainWindow endSheet:self.sheetWindow];
}
@end
```

Comment: Hi @Theis, thanks for the reply. What is the .sheetWindow property? I'm not sure how to do this part where you said, "Wire up the .sheetWindow property to the window, and the files owner to the classes included below. Also I've wired up a button in the xib file to the "closeWindow:" method, but that's entirely optional."

Comment: .sheetWindow is the NSWindow of the xib file (the root item). Wire up => Connect to the xib.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Are you saying to take the Window object (that will represent the menu) and connect it to the .xib for the SKView? What I have so far is this: I've created a SpriteKit OSX project. I added a User Interface Window file, which created a new .xib.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you turn on layer backing for any AppKit views or controls you want to be visible in front of your SKView. 
UIKit views all have CALayers built in. 
AppKit has them but not enabled by default.

You can do it in IB or in code with
[someViewOrControl setWantsLayer:YES]

Comment: Let's say I wanted to create an NSButton on top of my SKScene. Would I have to first create an NSView, embed the NSButton into that view and then do the setWantsLayer code? How does the SpriteKit code call AppKit controls? I apologize in advance if my questions are strange...I'm trying to get a handle on how this all fits together.

Comment: That's really another question to post separately. Short version is that app is an app whether it's on ios or os x. They both have a responder chain.

Comment: Ok, I'll post it separately.

Comment: I've posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658589/creating-appkit-elements-in-a-spritekit-game